# How to display the images (using posters from OMDb API) using html and only JavaScript in grid inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, omdbapi

I have been trying to display the trying to print the posters using `foreach()` loop, It displays only in the single column, use of class is not giving correct output instead it is making column inside one another because of the loop, how can I display the images in grid layer

**Below is my code,**

```
movies.forEach(movie => {
  output += `
    <div class="block">
      <div>
         <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}')" href="#">
           <img src="${movie.Poster}" class="box-1 border">
         </a>
       </div>
    <div>`
})
```

and display the html using the `innerhtml()`

Comment: _“use of class is not giving correct ouput”_ - impossible for us to tell what “correct” or “incorrect” would even be here, because we have no idea what that class is supposed to actually achieve, and how. Please provide a _proper_ [mre] that illustrates your problem.

Comment: .column{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
} if we add the class to seperate this is gonna creating inner columns not grid

Comment: There is no `column` class set on anything in that snippet you have shown us. Please don’t respond with such minimal snippets in comments, but do as you were asked to - provide a _proper_ [mre].